# Upload A Word Document and Get Its Custom Properties

Tags: javascript

I need an upload a document to a web site, but before I do that I need to check if the uploaded document has a certain property set (Word Document Properties/Metadata e.g. Author, Status, Approver).

Currently while uploading I can get only the following data:

```
{
    lastModified:1505983522536
    lastModifiedDate:Thu Sep 21 2017 10:45:22 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time) {}
    name:"TemplateTest.docx"
    size:18391
    type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    webkitRelativePath:""
}
```

Is it possible to get all properties while uploading a document?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless someone somewhere has written something that can parse Word documents in JavaScript, which I heavily doubt, this won't be possible.